# runtime error 1004 : excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting runtime error 1004, on the following line:

```
originBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
```

Here's the full code

```
Sub Obtain_Source()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim theOrigin, theString, newCol As String
    Dim lastRow, lastCol As Long
    Dim theRange As Range
    Dim originBook, originBookBackup, macroBook As Workbook
    Dim originOpen As Boolean

    originOpen = False

    Set macroBook = Workbooks("FY_Macro_Testt (DYNAMIC).xlsm")

    theOrigin = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsm; *.xlsx), *.xls' *.xlsm' *.xlsx", _
    Title:="Fiscal Year Selection: Select Only One", ButtonText:="Open", MultiSelect:=False)

    If TypeName(theOrigin) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "Don't just stand there.  Do something." & vbNewLine & _
               "Quit hitting CANCEL.  >.< ", vbExclamation, "WARNING.  CHOKING HAZARD."
    Else
        originOpen = True
        Set originBook = Workbooks.Open(theOrigin)
            lastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
            lastCol = originBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        originBook.Sheets(2).Visible = False
        originBook.Sheets(3).Visible = False

        originBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
        macroBook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 1).PasteSpecial
        i = 1000
       Do While 1000 <= 20000
           j = i - 999
            If originBook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Or _
               originBook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
                originBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(i - 1, lastCol)).Copy
               macroBook.Sheets(1).Cells(j + 5, 1).PasteSpecial

            End If
           i = i + 1000
        Loop
       originBook.Sheets(2).Visible = True
       originBook.Sheets(3).Visible = True
    End If

    If originOpen = True Then
        originBook.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

which one should I change?

Comment: can you add the full code?

Comment: what are te values of `lastRow` and `lastCol` ? Also, fully qualify your `Cells` with `Sheets(1)`

Comment: This loop `Do While 1000 <= 20000` will run forever. Because in 5 million years `1000` will still be <= `20000`. It should be `Do While i <= 20000` I think.

Comment: this is not my code actually. someone just ask me to edit it >.<

Comment: @JanPaulBartolo but this code can't work. Endless loops are nonsense.

Comment: ohh. my mistake, in here, its marked as comment

Comment: let me post a new one

Comment: Your error will almost certainly be because you are using `originBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy` instead of, as @ShaiRado pointed out, `originBook.Sheets(1).Range(originBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), originBook.Sheets(1).Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy`.

Comment: @YowE3k oh my god u are my savior D: it worked!

Comment: Thank @ShaiRado - he noticed the problem before I even looked at the question. (And I'll let him post that as an answer if he likes.)

Comment: @YowE3K it's all yours, got to do some charts for my boss (boring)

Comment: @ShaiRado - you're letting **work** get in the way of answering questions?!?!?!  Shock, horror!!!

Comment: @YowE3K  I totally agree :(

Answer (score 2):

Your error will almost certainly be because you are using

```
originBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
```

instead of, as @ShaiRado pointed out,

```
originBook.Sheets(1).Range(originBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), _
                           originBook.Sheets(1).Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
```

When they are not fully qualified, `Cells` references refer to cells on the `ActiveSheet`.  Excel is therefore having to try to copy all the cells on `Sheets(1)` that lie in the area between two cells on the `ActiveSheet`.  It's equivalent to saying "choose all the houses in **Los Angeles** that lie in the area between the intersection of E 79th St and 1st Avenue and the intersection of E 86th St and York Ave **New York**".  (Not living in the USA, I hope that analogy makes sense.)